# How can I get Spotify to play M4A files?

Tags: spotify, m4a

Spotify on Ubuntu 11.10 can only play mp3, does Spotify on Ubuntu support M4A, if so how can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I tried installing codecs to see if that was the issue and I can definitely play m4a files in Banshee, Rhythmbox, etc. It seems to just be a Spotify specific issue. I guess we're just going to have to wait until the developers move to GStreamer or something (or even their own codecs, I don't care, as long as it works.)

Sorry I couldn't be much more help.